# How to save a form on button submit in php

Tags: php, opencart

I am new to php. I am trying to save a form on button submit. But it saves the form when page render. I tried this .

**Php Code**

```
<?php
    if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
        $this->model_catalog_contactus->saveContact($this->request->post);
    }
?>
```

**Html Code**

```
<form action="/common/contactus" method="post" class="smart-green">
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
    <p><label><span>Name :
            </span><input id="name" type="text" name="contactname" placeholder="Your Name">
        </label><label><span>Email :</span>
            <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email">
        </label>
        <label><span>Mobile :</span>
            <input id="email" type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="Your Mobile Number">
        </label>
        <label><span>Message :</span>
            <textarea rows="" cols="" placeholder="Your message here" name="message"></textarea>
        </label>
        <label><span>&nbsp;</span>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="save" style="margin-top:15px;" name="submit-btn"/>
        </label></p>
</form>
```

Comment: post your html. Hope it is from Opencart

Comment: Yes , it is from opencart and MVC framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure that form is submitted, like this:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {

    if ($this->validate()) {
        $this->model_catalog_contactus->saveContact($this->request->post);
    }
}
```

Comment: OpenCart uses `$this->request->post` instead of `$_POST` and your two nested `if` conditions should be bundled into just one `if` using `&&`...

Comment: @shady Yeah, but to make it more clear, it would be better to separate steps for **beginner** and then start thinking about improving, `$this->request->post` or `$_POST` isn't that big deal since open cart's code base is terrible itself

Comment: If OpenCart programmers write terrible code they shouldn't blame OpenCart's code base. Consider it as a framework and that you should stick to it's conventions. If you don't like it, don't use it :-)